# what is document vector, paraghaph id in Doc2Vec

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am reading a paper about doc2vec. 
But I don't really get what is paragraph id and how it is trained...

I have tried to implement a sentiment analysis task with gensim package and succeeded, without knowing how exactly it works...

The paper said the Document vector is trained just like another word. But how is it processed? Is it trained at the same time with word2vec training? and how can it contain the message of the paragraph if it is treated as a word? 
And what is sentence label and one most confusing me is **the matrix D**...

Is there anybody can explain the process to me?
I got totally messed up... please help me...thx